# UILabels truncated in nested UIStackViews?

Tags: ios, uiview

I am trying to resize two vertical `UIStackView`s so that they would display the content the way I want. The two vertical `UIStackViews` are inside another horizontal `UIStackView`, which is inside a `UITableViewCell`. There are three `UILabel`s in each vertical `UIStackView`. Here's the current view hierarchy I have:

[image: View hierarchy]

The image view has their width and height constrained to have equal proportions. The horizontal stack view has an alignment of `.Center`, and a distribution of `.Fill`. Vertical stack view 1 has an alignment of `.Leading` and a distribution of `.EqualSpacing`. Vertical stack view 2 has an alignment of `.Trailing` and a distribution of `.EqualSpacing`. All labels have only one line and contents in stack view 2 are optional -- I set the `text` property to `nil` if I don't have to show anything in stack view 2 in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I have been trying to get the label in stack view 2 to show text properly without truncation. It is fine to have the text in vertical stack view 1 to be truncated, but it seems stack view 1 likes to resize itself to take up the majority of the width. Even stranger, this does not happen all the time. *It seems to happen more often when the labels in vertical stack view 1 are very short.* It also seems that the vertical view 2 is resized so it is only as wide as the very last label, which is usually the shortest among the three labels.

Here's what I've tried without success:

- Setting vertical stack view 1 to have a content hugging priority of high
- Setting vertical stack view 2 to have a content compression resistance priority of required
- Subclassing `UIStackView` so it returns an `intrinsicContentSize` with `width` as big as its labels' `intrinsicContentSize.width`
- Recursively setting the arranged subviews in vertical stack view 2 to have a content compression resistance priority of required

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I subclassed `UIStackView`, and in addition to overriding `intrinsicContentSize`, I also overrode `layoutSubviews` to invalidate its own intrinsic content size.

```
class NestedStackView: UIStackView {
    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        var size = super.intrinsicContentSize()

        for view in arrangedSubviews {
            let viewSize = view.intrinsicContentSize()

            if axis == .Vertical {
                size.width = max(viewSize.width, size.width)
            } else {
                size.height = max(viewSize.height, size.height)
            }
        }

        return size
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```